# Device driver entry points accessing

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

Can different *entry points* in a function be accessed by other drivers?

I know that by using `EXPORT_SYMBOL` we can do it for functions and symbols. My confusion is can `read`/`write` entry points be exported. If I do so will be against good driver practice?

Comment: The `read` and `write` are just function like other `EXPORT_SYMBOL` functions.  The difficulty comes in providing the parameters to `read` and `write`.  Normally this is done by a higher generic *file* layer that provides *inode* type data.  While what you propose can be done and maybe makes some sense if the data is **hard coded**, you would generally not want to do it this way.  Some *sub-systems* provide hooks for these, like *i2c* and *spi*, etc.  It might help if you could say a little more about the **device**.

Comment: lets consider a simple character device  for which i have written a driver...can you elaborate more on higher generic file which you mentioned....

Comment: `read()` is passed a `struct file*` and `loff_t *` for example.  If your routine doesn't use them, then it is not using the higher layers.

Answer (score 1):

You can export any Global function and Variable using EXPORT_SYMBOL() even device file operations read() and write() too. It will be very difficult to call them from any kernel modules because of the parameters required to call them for example file pointer of the device.